# viewDidLoad() not called

Tags: swift, viewdidload, nsviewcontroller

Either there is something weird in my project (Mojave, XCode10) or I am missing something very basic.

This is my whole code:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    public init () {
       
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.view = ConfigView(rect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300))
        print("2")
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        print("3")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("4")
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        print("5")
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        print("6")
        print("Is loaded: \(isViewLoaded)")
    }
}

class ConfigView: NSView {
    
    public init(rect: NSRect) {
        
        super.init(frame: rect)
        print("1")
    }
    
    required public init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I want to setup stuff in the `viewDidLoad()` method, but this method is never called. The console shows:

1
2
5
6
Is loaded: true

So, obviously `loadView()` and `viewDidLoad()` are not called, but afterwards when the view appeared `isViewLoaded()` shows true.

Why is that lifecycle method being ignored?

Comment: I think you’re supposed to assign to the view in the loadView method.

Comment: Thanks, saved me a tone of time! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you implement `loadView`, you *must not call `super`*. And you must make a view and assign it as `self.view`. Fix that and all will be well. Of course, in real life, you would never implement `loadView`, so all this is academic.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what is happening here is that since you are initializing the `view` property in the `init` function, when `loadView()` is called, it detects that the view has already been loaded and therefore does not call the `viewDidLoad()`.

Have you tried putting the view instantiation into the `loadView()` function instead of the `init`? In any case, I would not recommend creating the view in the `init` function.